# How to fill CupertinoActionSheet with JSON result in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am returning multiple records from JSON and need fill CupertinoActionSheet with them. How is done in dart? for example:

```
 CupertinoActionSheetAction(
     child: Text('item1'),
     onPressed: () {
        //print('pressed');
    },
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you want a way to generate as many `CupertinoActionSheetAction` widget as you have records in your JSON.

**Code example:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(child: ListView(children: [])),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// JSON example
final data = [
  {"item_id": "1", "name": "Item 1"},
  {"item_id": "2", "name": "Item 2"},
  {"item_id": "3", "name": "Item 3"}
];

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoActionSheet(actions: <Widget>[
      ...data.map((item) => CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: Text(item['name']),
          onPressed: () => print("Pressed ${item['item_id']}"))),
    ]);
  }
}
```

With this code there will be a `CupertinoActionSheetAction` generated for each entry in the map `data['items']`. And each time you will tap on one of the items it will be printed its name in the console.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: With this JSON format?   ` [{"item_id":"1","name":"Item 1"},{"item_id":"2","name":"Item 2"},{"item_id":"3","name":"Item 3"}]`